TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling') when I reload
I created a Laravel Vue website, it works well on my local server I run the "npm run build" command to get it ready for production. when I click the site url it works fine but I get this error whenever I reload the website
app-ece86485.js.page…ce.Af7c2vMr7B.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')
at nextSibling (app-ece86485.js.page…f7c2vMr7B.js:17:669)
at dn (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:34969)
at et (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:34729)
at Ze (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:34567)
at ge (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:35083)
at Ze (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:34356)
at ge (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:35083)
at Ze (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:34356)
at ge (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:35083)
at Ze (app-ece86485.js.page…c2vMr7B.js:13:34356)

and when I reload the site after a while it works fine. How can I solve it
App.js file


import '../css/app.css';
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

/* Import fontawesome icons */
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { ...} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { faGoogle } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

/* Add icons to the library */
library.add(...);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),

    
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) }, { mode: 'production' })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#1B998B',
    },
});
});

 

Vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
 
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    outDir: 'public/build',
    mode: 'production', // Ensure the build mode is set to 'production'
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'resources/js/app.js',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: 'resources/js/app.js',
      refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          base: null,
          includeAbsolute: false,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
});

